# Cannot run the sample android application in the codenvy emulator

Tags: android, codenvy

I tried creating an Android workspace with Codenvy with the sample hello world app provided. I built and ran the project. Clicked on 1(execute the run command) and then on 2(preview).
[image]

[image]

I never saw the hello world activity in the emulator screen and I didn't even see the app installed in the APPS section.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow this guide https://github.com/che-samples/mobile-android-hello-world/blob/master/README.md and install apk once an emulator is started.